# Integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{- \lambda x} dx$

Tags: calculus

What is the integral of the following? $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{- \lambda x} dx$$

I know the indefinite integral is $-e^{-\lambda x}$, but I'm not sure how you would evaluate it at infinity?

Comment: "Integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$" is redundant unless you really do want the integral of whatever number $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$ evaluates to.

Comment: Can we assume $\lambda>0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking you don't "evaluate at infinity" in Riemann integration. Instead you do this:

$$\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} - e^{-\lambda b} + e^0$$

The first equation here is the definition of an improper Riemann integral over an unbounded interval, while the second is using what you've already done. Can you take it from here?